# Should [lightsaber-combat] be a synonym of [lightsaber]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I just learned that we have a tag [lightsaber-combat](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightsaber-combat), used on 17 questions, as well as the tag [lightsaber](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightsaber) which is used on 138 questions.

Is it really necessary to have two separate tags, one for the weapon and one for combat using it?

### **Should these two tags be synonymised and/or merged?**

<sub>Note that if the answer is yes, this can be achieved in a few clicks without making any edits to questions.</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. The two are clearly synonyms of each other, with one of a far higher value than the other.

I'm torn. On a personal level, simply burninating  [lightsaber-combat](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightsaber-combat) seems the more sensible option, but one that will flood the front page with more than a dozen semi-worthless edits. On the other hand, turning it into a synonym leaves the worthless tag intact.

<s>I vote to synonymise it</s>. I vote for a moderator to **merge** the two tags.  It does less damage.

Comment: "*turning it into a synonym leaves the worthless tag intact*" - not necessarily. Mods can merge the two tags without creating a synonym, thus automatically retagging every [tag:lightsaber-combat] question as [tag:lightsaber] without bumping any questions.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Fair enough. Do that then.

Comment: In light of the overwhelming support in favour of merging the tags (+9/-0 on your answer at the time of this comment), I've gone ahead and done it. **[meta-tag:status-completed]**